# Append a certain text to user input to textbox html/js

Tags: javascript, html

Hi there wonderful people of Stackoverflow. So I am currently setting up a form for users to add data to the database. One of the the form-elements being a textbox where the value should be "nn minutes". I want the user to be able to edit the nn however the minutes should always append to the users input. How do I go about solving this?

Comment: by writing code?

Comment: do u have value range for that minute ??

Comment: yeah writing some code would actually help a lot... great answer prajwal

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post some code that you have tried. This will help people looking to answer this with better context (and, not to mention, shows the effort you have put in). Consider looking at the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try following:**

```html
<form>
  Select minutes spent:
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="00"><span> minutes</span>
  <br><input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

> **Note** type="number" not supported in IE9-

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your front end framework, you can use some masked input plugins to do that.
And if you are not using, jQuery it's a good one to begin.